# Search form in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, rest, express

I've created search form and going to pass parameters using post method to my node server.
On the server I call an API with those parameters in order to fetch results.
How can I return client to the same page updated for example with datatable containig results returned by API?

I know I can do it on the client side but my question is how to do it on server side?
Thanks in advance

sample html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/">
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

and server:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  let ENDPOINT = process.env.ENDPOINT;

  const params = {
    address: req.body.address,
    key: process.env.API_KEY,
  }

  ENDPOINT = ENDPOINT.concat((new URLSearchParams(params)).toString());

  request(ENDPOINT, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      /*
        here I would like to handle the response and
        return updated index html with records in datatable

      */
     res.sendFile('updated index html');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.  At least the server side code, include the client side if you could.

Comment: updated with code

Comment: Use `res.render` to call the template engine to transform the result to HTML.  Here is the documentation on it http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: What part doesn't work, it looks right to me

Comment: Thanks frogcoder this is what I was looking for 